# How can we remove round brackets around table name in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter project, I need to migrate whole database mysql to sql server, for that i am getting issue in select query, I can see in sql server round brackets are not supported around the table name, here is my codeigniter query

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
$this->db->select('*')->from('tb_card',false);
$this->db->where('company_id',$this->company_id,FALSE)->get()->row_array();
```

This select query generates below query

```
SELECT * FROM (tb_card) WHERE company_id = 27
```

You can see there is round brackets around the table name, i want to remove this, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Sounds like a potential X-Y problem. Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @JonStirling  this query are not supported in sql server so

Comment: Ah yes, should have done more than skimmed the question. :P

Comment: Doing some searching, have you updated your config to use the correct db driver? The parenthesis appear to come from those.

Comment: @JonStirling i am using odbc driver

Comment: Yes, but have you updated your code config to tell it you're using that? (Can't whether you were saying you had, or just that you're using that for connecting).

Comment: What i need to update in config ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164332/discussion-between-nikul-panchal-and-jon-stirling).

Comment: In your `database.php` file perhaps? There should be `dbdriver` index.

Comment: Yes, i need to set there odbc driver

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution
(/system/database/drivers/odbc/odbc_driver.php
In this path need to change the function like this way

```
function _from_tables($tables)
    {
        /*if ( ! is_array($tables))
        {
            $tables = array($tables);
        }

        return '('.implode(', ', $tables).')';*/
                if ( ! is_array($tables))
                {
                    return strstr($tables, ',') ? '('.$tables.')' : $tables;
                }
                else
                {
                    return count($tables) > 1 ? '('.implode(', ', $tables).')' : end($tables);
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you able use simple `$this->db->query($sql)` method, instead of Active Record.

```
$result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_card WHERE company_id = 27');
printr($this->db->last_query());
printr($result->result());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$this->db->get();` if you want select * (all)
for example, is something like....

```
function getcompany($company_id)
       {
         $this->db->where('company_id',$company_id);
         $query = $this->db->get('tb_card');
         return $query->result();
       }
```

those function will return like so

```
SELECT * FROM 'tb_card' WHERE 'company_id' = $company_id
```

hope its answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

please use this arcsecond  symbol in table name `tb_card`

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false; $this->db->select('*')->from('`tb_card`',false); $this->db->where('company_id',$this->company_id,FALSE)->get()->row_array();
```